# How do I install an APK file using Android Studio?

Tags: android

I have an APK file and my developer assistant said to use it to install the app onto my phone, question is, how can I do it? Just click run? I think I tried it and it's not working, only the workshop files were editable ones and could run.

Answer (score 2):

if you have ADB (android debugger) installed and set as environment path:

**1st option:**

i'd use that from cmd line. First you have to setup unknown sources from Settings menu and enable developer mode, and then trust USB Debug Options from your device. Go to system and you have to tap the version number a few times, you can google this. (That's how it used to be).

From Mac/Windows/Linux:
type:

To see if it's in path it should give you help:

```
adb
```

To enumerate devices connected via USB

```
adb devices
```

To install apk on your local machine to device (force install)

```
adb install -r ~/Desktop/some.apk
```

Or in Windows you can put your full path (force install)

```
adb install -r c:\Users\something\Desktop\some.apk
```

**2nd option:**

You can put APK on google drive, or some website you can access, even one drive or via email, then you can save it onto your device. Using ES File Manager, or some files manipulation tool, you can install it directly from there.

**3rd option:**

Use Google Play Beta or Alpha delivery methods. You can do a closed or open beta, and post it up there. That way all you need is a play.google link and then you will be able to install it, and manage updates via this method. I use this as I test alpha/beta APK Android Game deployment, and am able to distribute a URL (for open beta/alpha), and users can easily test it via this method. Amazon App Store and iTunes App Connect (iOS) has similar type options, too, but I'm just assuming you would distribute this App/Game via Play.

Remember if it's unsigned apk, you need to be able to enable side-loaded apks via your settings, app sources. If it's signed by a trusted developer then this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This is the  correct answer for my context in the same question. Efficient way to provision as a test engineer. Wish people would upvote or accept answers more often. Note: you may need to uninstall the existing app (manually) if you swap between production and development signed packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an APK file you don’t need android studio.

Copy the file to the device you want to run it on and open it. You’ll be promoted to either enable developer mode or trust the app as a one off occasion.

You’ll then be given the option to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to turn on "download from other sources" or something(I can not remember the option exactly) from your phone's setting. You can upload the apk file to google drive. And navigate to the directory use you phone, click and download file. And then you should be able to run and install the app to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try PdaNet+.

It will easily install android studio application to your android mobile.

Download PdaNet+ for PC.

In mobile open Debugging.For Debugging go to Settings -> About phone -> SoftwareInfo -> Build Number -> Click 7 to 8 times on Build Number.It will open Developer Option.Go back to Setting there you see Developer option.Then in Developer Option search for USB Debugging and open it.Then connect your mobile to PC with USB.

Insatll PdaNet+ it ask to connect mobile,connect it with USB it will download mobile software.

After completing your program,in Android studio click on 'Run App' (Green symbol as Play Button) then it will show your Android Mobile in Connected Device.Then it will install Android Studio application to your mobile.